# Save Date working but time wont save

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin

i am trying to save from date and from time to a calender list in sharepoint.

```
var listItemCustom = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
alert(listItemCustom);

var listItemFromTime = document.getElementById('timepicker').value;
alert(listItemFromTime);

newItem.set_item('EventDate', listItemCustom, listItemFromTime);
```

How do i solve to save To the EventDate column (date and time)

Comment: Does the alert message contain full date time value?

Comment: Yes it contains.

Comment: `newItem.set_item` will accept only two parameters. So you should pass the date and time in the second parameter by concatenating both values.

Comment: Alright how do i do this?

Comment: can you post how the value get displayed in the alert box. Then I can write specific code based on that

Comment: Like this 11/15/2014
Second 01:30Am I am using jquery to display that in my controls, cant really find were to change the format

Comment: Date will save even if i am using 11/15/2014 this format but time wont save like i posted in the top, because i dont not how to post two parameters to a date and time column

Comment: I have updated my answer. Try that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18683/discussion-between-amal-hashim-and-martin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the date time in `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ` format.

Where `yyyy` is the year `mm` is the month and `dd` is the day. Followed by character `T`. Then hour, minute and second followed by character `Z`

Something like

```
var string = '11/15/2014 01:30Am'.replace('Am',':00');
var d = new Date(string);
//yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ
var result = d.getFullYear() + '-' + d.getMonth() + '-' + d.getDate() + 'T' + d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ':00Z';
alert(result);
```

Then use

```
newItem.set_item('EventDate', result);
```

Comment: Hi cant save it... i added this istead ,  $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();

Comment: i wan to archive this, display value from two getitembyid and save to date and time column IF a sharePoint column has two values Date And Time how do i save from two different controls on for date and one for time in that column?

Comment: sorry your question is not clear can you explain a bit more or invite to a chat room.

Comment: Alright can u invite me?

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18683/discussion-between-amal-hashim-and-martin

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you're using JavaScript, Date objects have a native method called `toISOString` that will give you the date in a format that SharePoint expects.

This keeps you from having to re-invent the coding mechanism each time you want to use it, and having to calculate the difference from UTC to get an accurate time.

You can check it out in your browser dev tools JavaScript console:

```
>date = new Date("11/10/2014 2:00")
Mon Nov 10 2014 02:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
>date.toISOString()
"2014-11-10T07:00:00.000Z"
>date = new Date("11/10/2014 14:00")
Mon Nov 10 2014 14:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
>date.toISOString()
"2014-11-10T19:00:00.000Z"
>date = new Date("11/10/2014 2:00 PM")
Mon Nov 10 2014 14:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
>date.toISOString()
"2014-11-10T19:00:00.000Z"
```

Lines starting with an angle bracket are my input, the others are the output (from Chrome in my case, but this is a ECMA standard function implementation).

Something worth remembering is that `new Date()` objects initially use your local timezone while `toISOString` publishes 'Z' or UTC time. Also if you just don't put a time, the `Date` constructor will automatically give you `00:00:00` in your local time.